# Who committed most?

Tags: code-golf, string

### Background

Sometimes, people think you didn't work at your git project. But - you can prove yourself with `git shortlog -n`. Now, the problem is you are a programmer and programmers are lazy. So you want to write a program which shows the person who committed at most.

### Rules

You may not do the following things:

- use `git shortlog` with the argument `-s`
- use any alias, which calls git on any way

You may assume the following:

- git is installed on the system
- You are in the working directory of the repository where to find out the person
- The output of `git shortlog -n` will be piped in your program, but you may also call the command in your program, even though I can't see the advantage.
- If there is a language-specific package or library for git, you may use it.

### The output

Your program has to output the name of the person with the most commits in the repo.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the program with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: Language-specific rules are typically frowned upon. Did you [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) this?

Comment: @musicman523 No, sorry, I forgot to. The rules are only are workaround for languages who can't directly call a command, but I'll change it.

Comment: Please specify what is wrong with the question if you downvoted.

Comment: Can we assume that the user has no `(` in his name?

Comment: @ovs Yes, we can. It is realistic and anything else would be very annoying.

Comment: Could you add some input-output examples to the question?

Comment: @Leo Not at the moment, just clone any git repo and run the command

Comment: @Leo [Here](https://hastebin.com/kapakerifa) is an example output from [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina)

Comment: Is a trailing space accepted in the output? Some of the current answers actively try to avoid it, while others don't

Comment: @Leo Yes, it is

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 20 bytes

```bash
head -1|cut -d\( -f1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVjBbhs3EL37Kwg0he0mUuIALYrcXMdxDMSxYTltDwEKape7Yr1LsiQ3sop@Wm/9MPcNubviriQnbZxDkEjkcObNmzczmnO3uL9fCJ6zydFfWePZJP94wCbF0f39BbdeKvbTP397r4RlB0cvXxy@2mPhz7mSXvKKZbqupW8/PM5zNudOZsxY/bvIus8/mJx7wa5Pj19fnE7rPDluRSnumDZeauUYVzkrrTCs1rlw7bELYUvB5parbMH2a@68sPtMF6yUftHMp3DhVT1vRPDyuRVwmicvOFNJHwwOnjUVz8T440vEclobv2JFxUvm9fbbldYmnii03WXL42u3grM1E3e8NlX65byRVU72rdae5dICLG1X7YkTKwivd@cnp@9nI8BynTW1UJ4TYmRhjOqF/iS6F13/RKGrXNivR/Ra1NG@x22hG9c9BSYY2edsR8ZP7wAVOPVyskbnGeM9IPi/CZh2/k8fhwNwFgmKLAuYbabsjbyDEyVbwiBSmulSSSdVue0smbxuEPPR0YvO1WnyHRCyFTfJgxfcw/GRiYkI5QPSTyqpRGDUCMBBthNP/croxJKxUnly9oEXI4SmqSqE90cjnGffwP3C6ppdWV1aXr@5/PW5rSe@NsNsI0tIiyQ@hePTzFGBPwabCk7Eh@vP2BX0hp3v/uY8CbhuKi8dSCS68iOU0qqHt8oneHDEnarKDobenL9jfK4hhK/hAV75mVeNOPbeynnjxSNJEqKqxIQQbT3sVRWGapFLci2EB010XTDzFcujU9MxFJOIBQmTm7Jfzq8@r7zZgqtSVLp8nJhkqbQVMAuMW7UJlWyEdVqhUzSuQ@@DksWKSYq1CHVZQAGLQlgKMkbdGa4qvWS1vAvcLoZftuR8R2JMjeMmKXKA8JRJxxSuu4W2PvhycDjt7y61vWVOoPq8zBwZn6WUCcoZzswRMWIJuhDw3QZtcODk7fH7s9N3l2ejEyOlGLrvdC0iaHmDXpNFXY8UbD0ayQbiVA5dSdieJSHl7CDXwql9T1C3jXUl/GGXX34rRndDfK3g4fQXB3YSqDMyBj4hAQRVVnHnPldoQZZJhFwDCyE91@TEtNXblOEgVjjrEgVsNdYQM2rSuv7BGSIChZE/pdVkXunslg5JZZrNQaWA7EUukAdKLHu9l5SrsfYGEIczS7h8M2wlaB2E6dJSaKDWtsg6GYdjLTiJc08UEy7jRoQGvlY49Ew4dLe1ZNtj@0Pcx7kLEUxc8Jf5hegkJSSaOvGkDnKZLaT4FE9oY7STvfjtMBz6kKwyq5dRtJq589JDNF3AllpcIUTuHjbzVvsCyNCNC630w4ffI19znt06MG6RiL1rjLHCOWr8sqLsd6@vJchH@t1MhoqDKIgFG2wmszeTJMvXbXrjhz18NpSGBXbW8Sqxuq/31zbYciGRM6mcsN5FlPGXhSL5h0MeVifBNPAqKDs3vrGkKg0YE@BoU0HwDBjUzsIQ8zV0u84G5jz55mlgfPrZx1ArK9btBjOSNMDvbZPBEYKf/KQgB9YNt66fSQPrp2rb@@F2FxQUsfSLtPHUJJtI51ws@Cepm9h3nny3A8eQqUHB7VCoM4FGxyvp2r5K6JRWNybuKX15mz4YRPr1zZR0ITQFTKOOuqTVeZOhs0InCELQ0W@uXWizcYhs3fk2XVckzsYijFNhYHy6LoQTiLKEIiLKy3QdW6Pg0ONlgRalfLVKvI3KWUInO1N9NRniBdVTfAG2@8Ki2JIplSRjKapq7DfdOaOVkJw5RrM@6/bDzQipvJKeRDhsO7hjA@gKehZWvjhQdVU9iOqa1uUKfxGz/xRWt1OaAAeISIPDba@MD2/U3m/B5whAYHkvO5bGg4GArOVNk62WimEgn/VbKkOTwDbZ52cHt8dF8SXfdNI40zbsGgMW/X@@79C5sI9ZfStU1OmMuzSRuV0x26gOlFGxj2fbdpZvOzcB7Wgm3FB@qLYKOdf0hITzA/nfvFCv6ynJD@JrLHxTIH@jJJat0YjSQRkvYgoQr@BjNwCKpLtRTU/4klvxgDJf91qbhr7X/oBzqvLw680P/Y83hG3N7W2ul4qqcPsqMFwVv/8xUg0I5cJjOKieG4ppcjSEHg7funZq0WmXCPM@ujKR28cPMJBFtBsf/okysmXYd0kcwCHUGThE/YYIF38mAaZhZEXIgtcbZRbbPDnwUVG@uc0rmgRgBxXvkfu6vXJFS3OwRbP2xqTgkn1rVExRO2aUvBsCh0ZN5Ip42jY7pHt4h4rmP10YCdmX3e2G6g2xX0/O2EUURl5WINyttxL5c@MD8cSmHG8/HQ4ntN48Fvrc@myQtG7vPYibUWNpLUTSc02rjUE1Ho4txFF@bSeuaXvrXzXA/p78ce/Kd/6osUcakJynabSdtmhc/xc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 18 bytes

```bash
sed -n 1s/.\(.*//p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVvZciO5sX3XVyBiHkTZTamppaf70uEIDbXOaBtRbb/cF7AKJGEVCzUASlT5w/wD98PmZmKrAlhsqccO90OHhMKSyPVkJjSjavn774rlZFiSkTrY/9/B/p8ODqrffz9jZckVGRyNjvb@Z4eYfyteCkn0mtFnMoefFC3zmXiNvmZLWi6YIloQzV41lYwqN4HmORw0LcV6Rcto7JkXBVFrrrNlNF7AXjVdMMLLnL2O3RE0/0et9IqV2u/MV5UUL7CAl5lk@IUWRNS6qvVBzmb1YsHLhZ9bcs3hcyZWK66/e7Cq1RIpYwuaNWTOC7gr8uLlkMxo9szK/Hsn1tVCUrzty@GuImfnFzenT@d4pcLeRHPhuTXnrzAP79MQWvKV@UYGt1Nyni/YXp8g3FjJ1oGbY/cN2aWZrCSD/987b9wSEYlKr0VYqMZEsqqgGYyLkvUc811rWjouhxWTK1rw8jna6Ki7TV3lVMPgFVXPrCjcRKtdeKggP0/v71rdKrjS//FJlq6Tli43DtppFNWpxbuWgt6LnM85jI7IWtKqSvh4KalSHeFrlA7KKaW4VgwUQ@QMaf/6NBn3bOCP72rC@79NlrzaNhBUGkVsjJNkNFt2TPPfnqAlLVUlFDeGwaQUMacKnrFSsWB5VlNKumJEzAk4q5IS9sqyWtNZwWJlXUrGukKxdqAbOO5bE5OzJJsDWeBVUIm7m3j5GfVQAijSoMDgM6RYwZ7MUYd@FX6JXcgfWuQpuuFFk6hVzlA/8WMmgNmlhhFQG@CzUXr6QqeZ5JUet57X8BpNWEjdysNyZMWVwrWeJ8EW8jpjJFtwu1qB0ZOl1hXISSw840xsyGiZgS0j/@oSFv5WM6U3bMob00CxxZzWhVZ7759iScW7kS89Q@Owx2kFKsfIBKKCKB2rswIMqKI6Dl@3HH10MTw8@/awVQIMMxBQ0djZhnv9WkIgzTeUcmPYe8o5yM2Em9OHG5JDFGOZjtX0uve34GnOGgpCMMtj3VgJyQhKGU8FoqsGRQuS69If7S1@6f81nAUyLcExKaNTgDmM0raiW0uhWTIpjZ13fOWZWbBXjqQlGom2JpUmL0wqdA5agC1EhP3E6BsD019vuGZvDU2MDIrUCjaGTYgrEWDYUN1LIRk4q93bsiqxZl6C1C0wGIOPAeACg2ue6yV6OAiwICkEZsky4J@XM4RbUCocnNNn4DvIFDQ8Zy/gO5NVboVRtFZhvmdSCE0PYg3XXoKRo4sp4QIvAAJWGwFmLeQzlaIuc7Ph9TkZjcZRTMbgZN3e18ebeK2ajxEiFjX@tr@AKLEoUZ15afTkj0y2touwBJ2ccQhAFiyONgM3OueLWlrA1oLBWJvt3JwZx9S3JtUnXm4d8dzfnHVQK3lQiIwWBzNUBuFxPOk4MGTi6cN17292m4fmmW0b6MZpxYo5aBy4a2K9A7BQ16XxHhWVEHpBnxHjcJXte@DCVM9OL1Rys0zzFYPwv7nI8BT8ENzLhNooTATcaugAp7AU4DyqZZMmEYFiJ56Yx6LMQzJgt3xowLj6cJmd28JXo@NTo@Pd6B8w7YbXPy2qZZ09vzk2bVZq20AFkQnsQdLGJGXByBUDPwNu5FscB1ZWoHdguwUNAZkZ2aUfDetHRxu45/tmO74BsaLcPuRIHpO8AejGMw9sOgYfA2BvhDZAAasB7lU6WOvJFjr@vQVULmqTpJolD0wW5ARRBKLNDhLBj0j/mspcGTaBwc94wXXzX9v78f/@ldOtI6rC1KEKbsKEhzYp7SrMLqK1XWuGkKND3LCeGPKOF1S6TgXBuoMe7UuM8K0PFpS5bAAMLccIi79jvIsrFC7ZKZpqKQABLtEH0DayvvE5xBg3A4xp8nB89OP7Pnt/7BI/TMLaVHUr2HIIdFjPmjdGnmh2v23AI1f2mjEIUhBY10vABQBYMxPOkKXDDkszCK@6S9TXkpuskSrIGi@Gn6ODLrhkMxoS7d5BVYHOdVM2k@ALQKYSgKmQTSeT0JKvVi1KchmSdfkENLk0YM6zzh@UMM5eGc3GqiHeAjExLASfnBOaZTy3daIYR3kbUhp9igEUU/ujZ44DR97nhCsYrQe72AekGtMO2R2yOcQvPMGrhWLkFsIuz1wmccn1VT1zX5dAI7l6ur2x36wVuWSpx/oKQZEuMP8MbQDp6ZqfX5JzZX2yk8esnkNOGiXRFZleX17fPZk9IEpmbF4XoD88DoZ/56pN5lzxxvFlX8uGa1Giu9ovGUiOQ5R07DmAnG@I4AO5crhtS42gCpAg66Z/LqYHooomMbC34ZM1Bk9CRwUVkDm5f5ySJSRVwGhD8prNHP@Sg2Z88U@AD8K45OckgrGmSCPY5tBP97fWfwdcAB6SyQQqOMWOD7ioQcY62S8ZNOpQ8JmkqJzwrQ1gyUyHYzbO7CjpohCgWZiz1R683lJgCg9QJKPg/wgqDTr2p/PHWwuVrcA@OJO0kvhg03qwePRIXe8vpHfyxiO1afcIBkGmKOCCNt2t/SUYnm8ClzUXyQpG1duhxeOqNr/ZHFkwSD5RFX@rwZGZzEwRzNHAk2UFxxKJ4iHv7RYpkFJffFmYxGUTj4L9ZZijGm82hxCLHLw@j6g5M24ojSY99UOU1qNFrnC20qDLGArBAWvwPY9xrYoLQOCk1gYTmGMzIeU@UQ0sXOVG84ELRmo99U8xn3NIJBxxm0kU7O/tB3ehRnwVuAcG@mcqm7ZWDWcyq54xjIW9E1xyf/8QT1mCTD1l6AxtSSG@WLTifrlKadQSokTvZPiomjJLvlnRuVCOwlauHGY/2MqD867AenRFaIhxfM6KTYiMCG@4ATcfIdh/cHtbyWNMaW9dADd9/Y@9VsBJT4RKL7MUqJLuNp2Se2CCd9PY/BhbpNayIdrtChyFIH8XsshttoSktrfydotVvjKnpe6WJtJg63KRZ9YEiisQJSKd6f3dDbfFLFir@4vBuxmYutwNIBlJ2QXBDB0A3E3spk3xsDSKZQ5eorCM3wjYfv8fqkOqvU5d1srIKk@LIb38uKeKh7grCNbmaQGBjaAgTN3ZlmotwzsWjCm3sq2ybl5eQIiCyblsUO3MMSuIdhxYYWN9nO36YGhhwCCsbItrqkKfaqR@9fT0QA4/Hln4bkAawMS0wAT5OiXwI0XH1ud/TCYLbM1qMGosHQeA1PFGS9TV9sugjT173ej1ALjzhqtqVyEgAzWSIaIl6SH4KxpD0Luni58n7zUxzOGDrFGZSpvzwGw@N6WABsDi6zjVg65fBIatDE6CNDQ2vEdbQ/tJUrCBNnk3sCLmIcaUmQBhwHyYrJI6eslv45LW1HMFMOLg9gZC@t74Wzn3zc3fbsn1Y48Jmd4QwGLE/ooMIFaCmKzzylil93yvKJNNBdKNpYCSRRA@ASCLRUsLV0Utk5D6S8F4a1EzIfDkp@v7FgWG3L6vi2k3iaEMrSG6lhrCkG2GWsHsxdt14L1zeMYiMl0Eh1cJUWxdFMm829INK3iRe3TrTJoBc2koDbtKolll7B7zLmzuQogrGrOBdoVBNFOzYZyYjn/4cwxPbi7vb8inz@SSlZy9V9E3M8fThSjjEZP6TlLY5KkKTDHoyopvgN6ZSbiIFWZoRXvfZKXp9uq27l0yEnc/kFDjIaq2W2QdmqorrOebGU4OoXwGnHsZpR2fOWRrtTQNT9ihU2HbSpFkayGRDYGCDz29vhSB2WBhwJ4T/Ie2wdHx2MJ4d72koc6fEDxZgvawIWRODShIPcNIKAV4YzIwryD2l3oVnGRUOjQXHEzpHPLMPW9AqS7bm6yoXGD6pVTN0OWsMdEEEMNY4nLOWIa9Kp@PCo1nuETXKn1aszRObiEKXwBnKqMVw6SSm8qMqToYVOwxdW5S3E7sq8vfONBlEnRkoPT5hnzOxbqM8i0fKyeX1w6FEaxt26TP0mlZ39@AN2WNwR17rSEnwacZEN2iTgs@QTCGWis7uRPEXO/ZpYuxUeX5n2NzVTpp2l@AHsukwWTDEBlFg/L5TVO0kZQslhlESgc8sXLxdHb@GCP@69IWPuIocvd1@pCUrldgzxlPYqoUEJzUvn5N1tdyThNXryVH0yiofLdroi8x2J/UM@seo1FaNmlld7JkbVBtk4BeREYh31zNimZIU1POkuOsfreKpWLHPk51yXpvAz@t01HjKMJOr06Hhyefgv9ZSFvbQKBld4bARv3Mk9GhEWG0yGkJRDHInL0PAKGwuLY2a3z6SZZUgefwJZ@9jtUgPt4Nt@k1Fp@iIh/QJ8YafFWrpA1B8@FFQePBJ8hUpt0@yjfQycbcOSAe84wKueoXRleVbNj/VArcTadIhP6mLl30wDtJsVadkpgod3UfJ5Eq4JBujA8IXrSDEHuzBQdUqFolfXkYaVfsmkpg58mSZyAYcaq7vX2NHme2ze@nR0SE/lrT/NHwGH@apolNKuc7Frrtfk7/DlZ/Tn2zYozuVZsnSJ1OhGvRqx4nt5FzTh8S@FuBM5O3ooTM8VsPbd7rgvBmH0wd0Ph6DP7GCH@aTONmzK91BzHYa3bq5RN8DsKz9OUElvaMZ61LvHdlXzbC/lcJ1nFmju@YZKJTD1RhwWVw8TAJkPz8FQLJJC6jstlUABTXvmic4OIu7sEbAmyboMKPfXMGW4VYuTGbBExQawEp9UvstTiY0iYEuGqrVV2Rrjea2BUrYncDC4ezWmtMhQBc7EAmosng@CS8Q7XPJKJnma42GI3pJZfJkK9cvNIN0Dv5ma7SCpetyJ8/ITce7qdPSZ/ePSx1GhRdgr26VxqbteG/QU7dtE1hPBcUs31e1e2wJM3YVmlpa1OJvRsjVLpBTB0lT/a3TtI9Y3NsxmPIs0940leagQ@GZPtSYM4MRP82vJzcnOIXIM7UpPqoWdHcF10s@2jh9@yb7t4Js2YmMNs1GUpW67eXXE7j/sINnTUSruoLKnYlaKdc0jpWREudFotFYQOBq85GCUTfyXb58cfjbhvHFZg4Q8zchMrMQGLtS7sdQq/RFcRaY7RRaWzfT/TlxkFYLn4Z3Q2tHtgBX4phVhGHKMjRtzSz@98xhmpFH7MVJAf9mx131SuNSY9M8zKGflWRBM6VKIVtWGIbL3Y39QzuCPZgVP/29Ommjag/s80OkZ3hHsMcHJhVUya5qFXCnW62qZrVTBTg1IGVuEPS7jSPf8ih2exRgH3F2A@uIW1fNQFRo4/RQ9@tRY/NJwfgDJp@KTjl6XtADFpR6qFtvUevQe3S3lfXHYa7JNzUwqLntfYDZGgmQetixaAwcAK3kRZP3/KMLXlzv3Na5pCPA2p54WXzDEj28DCEga@2FP54fnp2e76/yv@Twy4m/ED278D9T8Do3voQniL2r9hEB9/z2bwv5XNf5AL/sdkHcKVG9sgW7DUZkz1jr1sHfFn@4n5yeoP6bn4YfvrywYQz6056UXfoyrsFbvhJNj7CYNJjAp3rjen2TwC6AHqFNXlXvG9DbJKNxsXMkMahO4UrsDXoERZlsWOZzAkyMrrYFp/D327oyF9h9nAAJBz8JWjz9dlfd3bsH8ncGsdbACgbtRjluu@PRywCTDvjna7Zeye4QuP7P2zryv@Ria4UwLBAbd4Z2OeMGG9wKO6W35pdK8jBQkr6w8hOrgBIFg1tDirsHA9HyUt920UALA5JFhZdZN3TIXxzGkiwopL5P70xl3SfTvOc7CLFQ0vxwa57zG1ERnYzlh0eZ4cjxo6/HH08/PwlYx/p/NNo9Pnz5/mPnxjL6I@Uzk92u/uZuvKWDUf50adPh7OTeTb7eHSY0/zoy2f28SQbUfpx9iWb/fjlEzum7PNuJJEOhUZbuycYsUCWICQHF7pDZ7LO/wlOMqghJvoeaoQ34eWiHNI2woqqcf3e8ETFQI4fyKB1S3vGF6Mt/EIVE3IB2h5Ocam8/5Mb2x3bWYK0qS4gLnem2kDRNvNsiwFfvBeQasAdvFZ0Fzkn3WIPDKQ7OwguZyJvRodHx93psWqY@4XaoWn2PEwud3b@Hw)

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 11 bytes

Run with `-n` (counted as +1 byte).

```bash
1s/ (.*//p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVtZcxs5kn7Xr6iIfpC0Y0qmDre93NgINXV2U0eL8swzWAWSGBWBagAlquaHzR/Y/7XeTFxVAIuW3DOxfnBIKByJPL/MhBQtvn0bqsNs7@A/Dg@rb9/OKedMZXvHw@P9/9zJzL8V40Jmek3JczaHnxThxUy8Rl/zJeELqjItMk1fNZGUKDeBFAUtsikX6xXh0dgzK8tMrZnOl9F4CXvVZEEzxgv6OnJHkOLvtdIryrXfma0qKV5gAeO5pPiFlJmodVXrw4LO6sWC8YWfy5lm8DkXqxXTPzxY1WqJlNEFyZtszkq4K/Li5SibkfyZ8uJHJ9bVQhK87cvRrsrOLy4nZ08XeKXS3kQz4bk1Z68wD@/TZISzlfmW7d1Os4tiQff7BOHGOF0Hbo7cN2SXprKSFP5/77xRS0QkKr0WYaEaZZJWJclhXHDac8wPrWnpuBpUVK5IyfhztNFxd5u6KoiGwWuinmlZuolWu/BQkf06vb9rdatkSv/bJ1m6Tlu63Dhop1FUpxbvWgp6Lwo2ZzA6zNaSVFXCxytJlOoIX6N0UE4pxbWioBiioEj716fxqGcDf3xXE97/bbxk1baBoNIoYmOcWU7yZcc0/@UJWhKuKqGYMQwqpYg5VbKcckWD5VlN4WRFMzHPwFlxktFXmteazEoaK@tSUtoVirUD3cBx35uYnCXpHMgCr4JK3N3Ey8@ohxJAkQYFBp8hxQr2pI469KvwS@xC/tQiT9GElU2iVgVF/cSPuQBmcw0joDbAZ6P05IVMc8kqPWo9r@E1mrCQupWH5ciKKYVrPU@CLRR1TrN8wexqBUafLbWuQE5i4RlnYkNOeA62jPyrOSz8o6ZKb9iUN6Y9RRdzUpda7b9/iiUV75Z96RkahT3OKlA5mo0hKgjuWJ2XYEAV0XH4umXoo8vB0fn3h60SYJiBgIrGTjfc61cOgbTYUMqNYe8p5yA3E27OHiZZAVGM5jpW05ve34KnOW8ICMEsj3VjJSTNUMp4KhBdNShakFyX/mhv8Vv/r@EskCkHx6SMTgHmMErbim4thabJpDR23rGVZ2ZJXxmSlmgk2ppUOnuhUqFz0AJsISLsF0reGJj@PmGavjU0NjIoUyvYGDYhjiPAsKG6l8Jsz1nt/pZViTUzDlK3wGAEPgaACwyuWaGX6OEgwIKkEJgly4B/Xs4QbkGpcHBOnoHvIFPQ8IK@gO9MVrkVRtFahfmRSSE0PYg1XHsJRo4uhsMFXgAErDYCzFrIZyJFzQuz4c1FNhyOopiMwcm6va@Pk3itmo8QIpY1/nawgCix4KjOjBs9@TOTre0iLEEnZxwCkAWLo83Ajc7ZopYWsLVgMNZmO7egxjH1rUn1ifGtI577m7MOayUPS5GT8nCGyiA8js86DgyZePZw0/ub3eaheabbBrpxWtFyDhoH7jqz3gFYqGtuvEdFJIRe0GfEOEzlBx64UNWz0wuRzCzTbEUh/G8uMjwFPwT3MqE2ChMBtxo6wCksBTiPatmkSUSg2Ikn5rHgRUgG7JYPDRhXHy6zc1v4anR8anS8G/0Dpt3w@mdltazz5zfHps1KbRuoIDKBPUjSmKQsGLmi4GfAjXyP48DKCvQObLckISBTI7v0o2H98HgD9/zYbMc3IFbw7UOO5FFWNADdWO6BTcfgYwDsjdAGKGA1wL1KB2s93ULHv7aAyEVtklSz5IHKMjtFFIFos4NE8CPSvyayUIZNYPAzVjLd/L/t/fg//yzI1hFVYepQBTdhwkOblHYVZhfR2q41Q8jRIW5YTwx5xwsqXaeCYN1Bj/YlRvjWBwvKXDYAhlZghMXfMd7FFQqX7JRNtRSAAJfoA0gbWd/4HGKMmwHGNH44Of75fZ@9P3aJHyZhbaq6FWw5BDqoZ80bI08kv9824JErfc0pBCkIrOsl4AIArLkJZ8jSQYelOYRX3SXqK2cmayQKssbLwefooEsm6YyERLt3UFWgc92UzST4ApCpBGAqZNPJJLRkq1WLklyGZF1@BprMDZjzrPMHJYyzV0azsWqIt0BMDAvBJxcZyXNW2DpRjKO8DSmNPsUAiqn90TPHgSPvc8IVjNaDXRwAUo1ph@wO2RziF57g1ULR7BbCLstdJnHF9HU9c1@XQGN2/XQ7sd@sFblkqcf6SkGQLjD/HG0A6eman19SMGV9spPHrJ5DThol0VU2vbm6uXsye0CUzOm8LkF/WBwM/8ZUm8y54o3jy4GWDdOCo7s64BQkxyBKOvYcQs43QPCBXDnatqVGUAVIkHbTPxfTA1FlkxjY2/DJGoMnoaOCCsgc3z9OsyUkVcBoQ/Kazhz/koNmbPEPgA/CuOTnJILRpkwj2ObQL/e31n8HXAAeksoEKjjFjg@4rEHGOtkvGTTqULKZJKic8K0NYMlMh2M2zuwo6aIUoFmYs9UevN4SYAoLUCQn4P8yVBp07E8Xj7cWKluBfXAmaSXxwab1YPHokbreX0jv5I1HatPuIQyCTFHAJWm6W/tLUDzfBC5rLpKWlKi3Q4vHVW1@szmyoJB8oir@UYMjM5mZyjBHA0@WlwxLJIqFvLdbpEBKffFlYRKXTTwK9pdjjmq82RxCLHLw5iKi5ty4oTSa9NQPUVqPFrnC2UqDLmMoBAeswfc8xrUqJgCBZ7U2mMAcmwspDzLVwMJVYTQfuGCk1lP/FPM5g0TCEbeZRMH@3n5wF2LEV4F7oKB/prJpa9VwJrXqGcNY2DvBJff3D/GUJcjUU4bO0JYU4otFK@6Xq5RGLSFK9E6Gj6rhefLNis6FchS2cuUw@8FWHpx3BdajK0JDjONzXm5CZER4gw24@QjB/oPb20oeY0p76xK46et/9LUCTnoiVHqZpUCVdLfplNwDE7ybxubHyCK1lg3RbtfgKET2NyHLwmZLSGp7K2@3WOXjBeG6W5pIg63LRZ5pEyiuQJSIdKb3dxNmi1mwVvcXg3dzMHW5G0AykrILghk4ALib2E2b4mFpFMscjKOwjN8I2P7g76pDqr1OzcG@CoPfkj17@XFPFAtxV2RYmyclBLYMBWHqzrZUaxnesWBMuZVtlXXz8hJCFEwuZINqZ45ZQbRjwAob6@Ns1wdDCwP2wsq2uKYq9KlG6tdPTw/Z0cdjC98NSAOYmBaYIF8nGfxI0LH1@R@TyQJb8xqMGkvHASB1vNESdbX9stfGnv1u9HoA3DlhqtpVCMhAjWSIaEl6CP6KxBD07uny1/F7TQxz@CBrVCZucx6YzeamFNAAWHwdpXrQ9YvAsJXBSZCGxob3aGtov0gCNtAm7wZWxDzEmDITIAyYD5NVUkfn7DYuaU09VwAj7t1OIKTvj76Xc08mf73Nbh57TMj0hgAWI/ZX2R7EShCTdV45rfS@7xXlsqlAurEUULIIwscAZLFoaeGqqGUSUn8rKWstaiYEnvx0c9@iwJDb93Ux7SYxlCE1RFeuIQzZZqgVzH68XQfeO4dnLCLXZXB4lRDl1kWRzLst3bCClYVHt86kKTCXhNKwqySaVcbuMe/C5i6EuLIxG2hXGEQzNRvGienop7/E8GRydT/JPn3Orihn9L2Kvpk5ni0Ej0dM6jtOYZOnKjDFoCsrvj30zlTCRawwQyva@yYrTbdXt3XvkpG4@4GEGg9Rtd0i69BUXWE938xwcgjlM@DcyzDt@MwhW6ulaXjCDp0K21aKJF0LiWwIFHzo6fWlCMwGCwP2nOA/tA2OjscWxrvrJQl1/oTg8RK0hw4gc2pAQeoZRkIpwBtne@YVxMFSr4KTjEqH5oJ7UzKHPHPfG1Cqy/YmKyIXmH4pVVN0OWtMNAHEUJq4nHOaY6/K56NC4xku0bVKn9YsjZNbiNIXwKnKSUUxqWSmMmOqDgYVe0xdmBS3E/tq/gcDukyCjgyUPt@Qz4VY8yjf8rFyfHXjUFiGtW2b9Fk6Lev7G/CmrLF3R19ryEnwaQZEt6jTgk8QjKHWyk7uBDHXe3bpYmxURfGX2FyVTpr2l6DHMmkw2TCUDaNB@fymKdpImi2WOURKBzyxcvF0fvEYI/4bbgsfcRS5@zp9SErXK7DnnCUxVQoITupAvybrazkniavXkqFplES@2zWRlxjsj@uZdY/RKOFNWtkdL2kbVNskoBeREcg3V7OyGZDUlPPkOKvfrWKp2LGPUl2y3tvAT@t01CiKsNPrs8HR6afgfxbS1jYQaNmdIbARP/N0eGREGC1yWgJRDDJn7wNAKDSurc0an35mS6LAc/iSz37HahAf74bb9BqLT1GRD@gTYw2@rlXShiDF4LIk8eATZCrTbh/lO@hkY@4cEI95RoVc9Qujq0o66H8qBe6mUyRCf1NzFz3wTlKsVackJviu7uMkUgUc0o3xAcGLdhBib7bggApRq6QvDyPtil1TCew8WfIMBCNOdbe3r9HjzLb5/fSIiNDfa1I8Gh7jT9M0sUnlfEdDt93P6d/B6s@Zb1aM0L1q8wSp04lwLXrV4@Q2cs7pQwJ/K3Bm8lZwyBy/99DmvS4Ib/bB1AGNr8fgb4zwl/E0bsb8XncQg71mp14@xucgLE9fTmBpz3jWmuO9K/uyEfa/TrCOM3N8xyQTnXogCgsue5cP4wDJL14hkIzjMiqdTQVAce2Lxgku7uIevCHAtjEq/Mg3Z7BViJUbs0nABLUWkFK/xF6LgSltQoDrtlrVFel6o4ld0TJ2N7BwMKu1xlQIwMUOZCI62zs5De9Q7TOJ6Fmmqw1GY3rJZDLkKxevZAP0jn8lq7TCZSvyF0/IjYf76VPSp3cPS50GRZegr@6VxmZt@K@QUzdtUxjPBcVsn1d1OyxJM7ZVWtLaVGLvxgiVbhBTR8mT/a2TdM/oHJvxGPLsE570lWbggyHZvhSYUwPRvw8vx5Mz/ALEmZpUHzUrUviii2UfKf2efdPdO2HazARmuyZDyWv99pKradxfmJBZI@GqvqBiV4J2yiWpY0W01GmxWJQ2ELjqbJRA9J1sl598POm2cVyBiVHEzE2ozOxJrH1pt0PoNbqCWGuMNiqN7PuJvtw4CMvFL6O7odUDO@BLMcwq4hAFOfqWZnb/O8ZQrehjtoLkoH@zk656pTHpkWrGY@hXlUngXAkubMMS23ixu6lncEewB6P6t2dPkzai/ko3O0R2hnsMc3hoVk2pZKJWCXe62aZqVjNRglMHVuIOSbvTPP7JjsxmjwLsK8Z@cA1p@6oJiBp@jB76bi16bD45AGfQ9EvBKU/fA2LQCq4HtvUevQa1S3tfXXcY7pJwUwuLntfaD5ChmQStixWDwsAJzEZaPH3LM7bkzf3OGS8gHwfU8sJ48wxI9ugohIGvthT@eHF2fntxsCr@ncMuJvyUHdyB@x@D0b31ITxF7F@xiQ5@5LN5X8rmvsgF/mOzD@BKjfSRLuhrMiZ7xl63Dviy/OX9@GyC@m5@GHz68sGEM@tOelF36Mq7BW74STY@wmDSYwKd643p9k8AugB6hTV5V7xvQ2ySjcbFzJDGoTuFK9A16BEWZbFjmcwJMjK62Bafw99u6MhfYfZwCCQc/lfQ5pvz/97ZsX8kc2scbwmgbNhilJu@Px6xCDDtjHe6Zu@d4AqN7/@wrSv/Zya6UgDFArV5Z2CfM2K8waG4W35rdq0gBwsp6U9DO7kCIFk2pDmssHM8GCYv9W0XAbA4JFlYdJF1T4fwzWkgwYpI6v/0xlzSfTorimwXKR5Yig933WNuI7JsN6f50Ul@NKT05Mvxx6PPX3L6kcw/DYefP3@e//yJ0pz8TMj8dLe7n6krb9lwWBx/@nQ0O53ns4/HRwUpjr98ph9P8yEhH2df8tnPXz7RE0I/70YS6VBotLV7ghELZAlCMnChO2Qm6@If4CSDGmKi76FGeBPOF3xA2ggrqsb1e8MTFQM5fsr2Wre0b3wx2sJvRFEhF6Dt4RSXyvs/ubHdsZ0lSJvoEuJyZ6oNFG0zz7YY8MV7CakG3MFrRXeRc9It9sBAurOD4HImimZ4dHzSnR6rhrlfqB2aZs/D@Gpn539d4vdtwP8P)

Comment: Personally I would just call this a sed answer, not a Bash answer

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 10 bytes

```
~:'(-!#@_,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVjBbtw2EL3nK1gkhe0m2sQBWqQ@1XUcx4AdG16n7SFAwJUoLWuJVEkq6@2hX9ZbP8x9Q0paSrvrpI1zCBItOZp58@bNjGYib1Qhkh9f3d39dbCzm3zz@KePz@7uzrlxUrGf//nbOSUM291/@WLv4BHzf06VdJKXLNVVJV378DDL2IxbmbLa6N9F2j1/X2fcCXZ1fPj6/HhSZdFxIwpxy3TtpFaWcZWxwoiaVToTtj12Lkwh2Mxwlc7ZTsWtE2aH6ZwV0s2b2QQuHFSzRngvnxsBp3n0BluX0nmDg9fWJU/F@PEFYjmuardkeckL5vTm26XWdTiRa7PNlsPPdglnKyZueVWX8Y@zRpYZ2TdaO5ZJA7C0WbYnjowgvM5Oj47fTUeAZTptKqEcJ8TIwhjVc/1JdG@0/StyXWbCfD2iV6IK9h1uC93Y7lVgQi37nG3J@PEtoAKnXiYrdJ4x3gOC/9ce087/ycNwAM4iQYFlHrP1lL2Rt3CiYAsYREpTXShppSo2nSWTVw1i3t9/0bk6iX4DQqbkdfTCc@7g@MhEInz5gPRJKZXwjBoBOMh25Klb1jqyVBupHDl7zxsDhHVTlgjvj0ZYxx7D/dzoil0aXRhevbn47bmpElfVw2wjS0iLJD7545PUUoE/BJtyTsSH68/YJfSGnW7/5TQKuGpKJy1IJLryI5Tiqoe3ykV4cMQdq8oWhl6fnjE@041jr@EB3vILLxtx6JyRs8aJB5IkRFWKhBBtPexVFYYqkUlyzYcHTbRdMLMly4JTkzEUScCChMlO2K@nl59X3nTOofqlLh4mJlkobQTMAuNWbXwl18JYrdApGtuh917JfMkkxZr7usyhgHkuDAUZou4Ml6VesEreem7nwx9bcp6RGFPjuI6KHCA8ZdIyhet2ro3zvuzuTfq7C21umBWoPidTS8anMWW8cvozM0SMWLwueHw3QesdOHp7@O7k@OziZHRipBRD962uRAAta9Br0qDrgYKtRyPZQJzKoisJ07PEp5ztZlpYteMI6raxLoXb6/LLb8Toro@vFTyc/uLAjjx1RsbAJySAoEpLbu3nCs3LMomQbWDBp@eKnJi0ehszHMTyZ22kgK3G1sSMirSuf@EUEYHCyJ/SKpmVOr2hQ1LVzfqgkkP2AhfIAyUWvd5LytVYez2Iw5nFX74ethK0DsJ0YSg0UGtTZJ2Mw7EWnMi5J4oJm/Ja@Aa@Ujj0TDh0u7Fk22M7Q9zHufMRJNb7y9xcdJLiE02dOKm8XKZzKT6FE7qutZW9@G0x7PuQLFOjF0G0mpl10kE0rceWWlwuRGbvN/NWuxzI0I1zrfT9h98hXzOe3lgwbh6JvW3q2ghrqfHLkrLfvX0lQS7Q7zoZKg6iIBassZnMXidRlq/a9IaHPXzGl4YBdsbyMrK6o3dWNthiLpEzqawwzgaU8ZeBIrn7Qx5WJ8E08MorO69dY0hVGjDGw9GmguAZMKidhSHmK@i2nfXMefL4qWd8/OyDr5Ul63aDKUka4HemSeEIwU9@UpAD6zU3tp9JPesnatP7/e0uKChi4eZx46lINpHOmZjzT1I3oe88@W4Ljj5Tg4LbolAnAo2Ol9K2fZXQKYxu6rCn9OVd98Eg0q9vpqQLvilgGrXUJY3OmhSdFTpBEIKObn3tQpsNQ2TrzrfxuiJxNhRhmAo94@N1wZ9AlAUUEVFexOvYCgWLHi9ztCjlymXkbVDOAjrZmeqrqSZeUD2FN8B2X1gUWzSlkmQsRFmO/aY7J7QSkjOHaNYn3X64HiGVV9STCIdNB7dsAF1BT/3KFwaqrqoHUV0Jjif4i5j9pzC6ndIEOEBEGhxue2V48VrtffQ@BwA8y3vZMTQeDARkJW@abLVU9AP5tN9SGZoEtsk@P1u4PS6KL/mlk8apNn7XGLDo//N9i875fczoG6GCTqfcxonMzJKZRnWgjIp9PNu2s3zbuQloSzPhmvJDtZXPuaZXSDg/kP/1C9WqnqL8IL7GwDcF8jdKYtkajSgdlOEipgBxAB@7AVBE3Y1qOuELbsQ9ynzVa20c@qP2A86xyvzXmx/6jzeEbcXNTaYXiqpw8yowXBW/fxWoBoQy4TAclM9riinZH0IPh29sO7XouEv4eR9dmcjtwgMMZAHtxvl/ooxM4fddEgdwCHUGDlG/IcKFzyTA1I@sCFnwaq3MQpsnBz4oyjc3WUmTAOyg4h1yX7VXLmlp9rZo1l6bFGy0b42KKWjHlJJ3TeDQqIlcEU/bZod0D@9Q0fynCyMh@7K73VC9JvaryRm7iMLIy3KEu/FWJH92fCCcWJfjzaf94YjW68d8n1ud9ZLW7b27YTNqDK2FSHqmabWpUY17YwthlF/ZCWvao9VXDbC/J3/Yu7KtHzUekQZE52kabact/9XlXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 8 bytes

```
s` \(.*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVjBbtw2EL37Kwgkhe0ku4kDtChycx3HMWDHhu20PQRouRKlZS2RLEllvf223vph7htS0lLaXSdtnEOQaMnRzJs3b2ZkhZeK39@739mnvemznfv7c27xiP30z9/eK2HZ3sHrV/tvdlj4c6qkl7xima5r6duHh3nOZtzJjBmr/xBZ9/yjybkX7Or48O358bTOk@NWlOKOaeOlVo5xlbPSCsNqnQvXHjsXthRsZrnK5my35s4Lu8t0wUrp581sChfe1LNGBC9f2hBH8gZnKumDwcFrTcUzMX58gViOa@OXrKh4ybzefLvS2sQThbbbbHn87JZwtmbijtemSn@cNbLKyb7V2rNcWoCl7bI9cWQF4XV2enT84XoEWK6zphbKc0KMLIxRPdefRfdG17@i0FUu7LcjeiXqaN/jttCN614FJhjZ52xLxo/vABU49XqyQucF4z0g@L8JmHb@Tx@HA3AWCYosC5itp@ydvIMTJVvAIFKa6VJJJ1W56SyZvGoQ88HBq87VafIbELIVN8kLz7mH4yMTExHKB6SfVFKJwKgRgINsJ576pdGJJWOl8uTsA2@MEJqmqhDen41wnj2B@4XVNbu0urS8fnfx60tbT3xthtlGlpAWSXwKx6eZowJ/DDYVnIgP11@wS@gNO93@y2kScN1UXjqQSHTlRyilVQ9vlU/w4Ig7VZUtDL05PWN8phvP3sIDvOVnXjXi0HsrZ40XjyRJiKoSE0K09bBXVRiqRS7JtRAeNNF1wcyWLI9OTcdQTCIWJExuyn45vfyy8mZzrkpR6fJxYpKl0lbALDBu1SZUshHWaYVO0bgOvY9KFksmKdYi1GUBBSwKYSnIGHVnuKr0gtXyLnC7GP7YkvOMxJgax01S5ADhOZOOKVx3c2198GVvf9rfXWh7y5xA9XmZOTJ@nVImKGc4M0PEiCXoQsB3E7TBgaP3hx9Ojs8uTkYnRkoxdN/pWkTQ8ga9Jou6HinYejSSDcSpHLqSsD1LQsrZXq6FU7ueoG4b61L4/S6//FaM7ob4WsHD6a8O7ChQZ2QMfEICCKqs4s59qdCCLJMIuQYWQnquyIlpq7cpw0GscNYlCthqrCFm1KR1/QuvEREojPwprSazSme3dEgq06wPKgVkL3KBPFBi0eu9pFyNtTeAOJxZwuWbYStB6yBMF5ZCA7U2RdbJOBxrwUmce6qYcBk3IjTwlcKhZ8Khu40l2x7bHeI@zl2IYOKCv8zPRScpIdHUiSd1kMtsLsXneEIbo53sxW@L4dCHZJVZvYii1cyclx6i6QK21OIKIXL3sJn32hdAhm6ca6UfPvwB@Zrx7NaBcfNE7F1jjBXOUeOXFWW/e/tKgnyk381kqDiIgliwxmYyezNJsnzVpjc@7OGzoTQssLOOV4nVXb27ssEWc4mcSeWE9S6ijL8sFMk/HPKwOgmmgVdB2bnxjSVVacCYAEebCoJnwKB2FoaYr6DbdjYw5@mT54Hx6bNPoVaWrNsNrknSAL@3TQZHCH7yk4IcWDfcun4mDayfqk3vD7e7oKCIpZ@njacm2UQ6Z2LOP0vdxL7z9NkWHEOmBgW3RaFOBBodr6Rr@yqhU1rdmLin9OVt@mAQ6bc3U9KF0BQwjTrqklbnTYbOCp0gCEFHv752oc3GIbJ157t0XZE4G4swToWB8em6EE4gyhKKiCgv0nVshYJDj5cFWpTy1TLxNipnCZ3sTPXVZIgXVE/xDbDdFxbFlkypJBkLUVVjv@nOCa2E5MwhmvVJtx@uR0jllfQkwmHTwS0bQFfQ12HliwNVV9WDqK4ExxP8Rcz@S1jdTmkCHCAiDQ63vTK@eK32fgs@RwACy3vZsTQeDARkJW@abLVUDAP5db@lMjQJbJN9frZwe1wUX/NLJ43X2oZdY8Ci/8/3LToX9jGrb4WKOp1xlyYyt0tmG9WBMir28WzbzvJt5yagHc2Ea8oP1VYh55peIeH8QP7XL9Srekryg/gaC98UyN8oiWVrNKJ0UMaLmALEG/jYDYAi6W5U0xO@4FY8oMxXvdamoe@0H3COVR6@3vzQf7whbGtub3O9UFSFm1eB4ar4/Y@RakAoFx7DQfXSUEyTgyH0cPjWtVOLTrtEmPfRlYncPj7AQBbRbnz4J8rIlmHfJXEAh1Bn4BD1GyJc/EwCTMPIipAFr9fKLLZ5cuCTonxzm1c0CcAOKt4j93V75ZKW5mCLZu21ScEl@9aomKJ2XFPybggcGjWRK@Jp2@yQ7uEdKpr/dGEkZF93txuq18R@NTljF1EYeVmBcDfeSuTPjQ/EE@tyvPl0OJzQev1Y6HOrs0HSur13L25GjaW1EEnPNa02BtW4P7YQR/mVnbim7ay@aoD9Pfnj3pVv/aixQxqQnKdptJ22wleXfwE) Example input is the output from `shortlog -n` from Retina.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```python
print(input().split(' (')[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVhtb9RGEP7Or1ipVEkKd7xUrSq@pRBCJAIoCW2lUlV79tq3jb3r7q65XH9bv/WH0Wdmbd/adxdogQ8IfLvjmWeeeWbGzTosrfn2w4fGaRMOtWnacHg0902lw@GBODw4@vXhb0cfPpxLF7QRP/7zdwhGOXH46PHDoyd3BP85MzpoWYnM1rUO3cPjPBcL6XUmGmf/UFn//G2Ty6DExcnxs/OTeZ0nx50q1Y2wTdDWeCFNLkqnGlHbXPnu2LlypRILJ022FAe19EG5A2ELUeqwbBdzuPCkXrSKvXzgFJyWyRs4LjY4em1TyUxNH79GLCd1E9aiqGQpgt19u7K2iScK6/bZCvjZr@FsLdSNrJsq/XHR6ion@87aIHLtAJZ16@7EU6cIr5dnT09eXU4Ay23W1soESYiRhSmq5/a96t/oh1cUtsqV@3xEL1Qd7QfcVrb1/avAhEYPOduT8ZMbQAVOPZ5t0Lkv5AAI/t8wpr3/8y/DATiLBEWWMWbbKXuub@BEKVYwiJRmtjTaa1PuOksmL1rE/OjRw97VefIbEHKVbJIXnssAxycmZorLB6SfVdooZtQEwFG2E0/DurGJJa5kcvaWN0YIm7aqEN6frfJBfAX3C2dr8cbZ0sn6@etfHrh6FupmnG1kCWnRxCc@Ps88FfiXYFMhifhw/b54A70RZ/t/OUsCrtsqaA8Sqb78CKW06uGtCQkeEnGnqrKHoVdnL4Vc2DaIZ/AAb/lJVq06DsHpRRvUF5IkRFWpGSHaeTioKgzVKtfkGocHTfR9MIu1yKNT8ykUs4gFCZOfi5/P3nxcebOlNKWqbPllYtKlsU7BLDDu1IYruVHOW4NO0foevbdGF2uhKdaC67KAAhaFchRkjLo3XFV2JWp9w9wuxj925HxJYkyN4yopcoBwT2gvDK77pXWBfUGXG@6urLsWXqH6gs48Gb9MKcPKyWcWiBixsC4wvrugZQeevjh@dXry8vXp5MREKcbue1urCFreotdkUdcjBTuPJrKBOI1HV1JuYAmnXBzmVnlzEAjqrrGuVTjq8yuv1eQux9cJHk5/cmBPmToTY@ATEkBQZZX0/mOFxrJMIuRbWOD0XJAT805vU4aDWHzWJwrYaWxDzKhJ64YXXiIiUBj5M9bMFpXNrukQzzlbg0oB2YtcIA@MWg16rylXU@1lEMczC1@@GrcStA7CdOUoNFBrV2S9jMOxDpzEubtGKJ/JRnED3ygceiYcutlZst2xgzHu09xxBDPP/oqwVL2kcKKpE89qlstsqdX7eMI2jfV6EL89hrkP6SpzdhVFq134oANE0zO21OIKpXJ/u5kXNhRAhm6cW2NvP/wK@VrI7NqDcctE7H3bNE55T41fV5T9/u0bCQqRflezseIgCmLBFpvJ7NUsyfJFl974cIDPcWk4YOe8rBKrB/ZgY0Oslho508YrF3xEGX85KFK4PeRxdRJMI69Y2WUTWkeq0oIxDEeXCoJnxKBuFoaYb6Dbd5aZc/ere8z49Nk7rpW16HeDS5I0wB9cm8ERgp/8pCBH1hvp/DCTMuvnZtf7@XYfFBSxDMu08dQkm0jnQi3le23b2HfufrMHR87UqOD2KNSpQqOTlfZdXyV0SmfbJu4pQ3k3QzCI9PObKekCNwVMo566pLN5m6GzQicIQtAxbK9daLNxiOzc@TpdVzTOxiKMUyEzPl0X@ASiLKGIiPJ1uo5tUPDo8bpAizKhWifeRuUsoZO9qaGaGuIF1VN8A2wPhUWxJVMqScZKVdXUb7pzSishOXOMZn3a74fbEVJ5JT2JcNh1cM8G0Bf0Ja98caDqq3oU1YWSeIK/iNl/KWe7KU2BA0Sk0eGuV8YXb9Xe7@xzBIBZPsiOo/FgJCAbebNkq6MiD@SXw5Yq0CSwTQ752cPtaVF8yi@9NF5ax7vGiEX/n@97dI73MWevlYk6nUmfJjJ3a@Fa04MyKfbpbNvN8l3nJqA9zYRbyg/VNpxzS6/QcH4k/9sX6k09JflBfK2Dbwbkb43GsjUZUXoo40VMAeoJfOwHQJV0N6rpmVxJp25R5otBa9PQ73QfcE5Mzl9vvh8@3hC2tXTXuV0ZqsLdq8B4Vfzuh0g1IJSrgOGgetBQTLNHY@jh8LXvphabdgme99GVidwhPsBAFtFuA/8TZeRK3ndJHMAh1Bk4RP2GCBc/kwBTHlkRspL1VpnFNk8OvDOUb@nyiiYB2EHFB@S@7q68oaWZbdGsvTUp@GTfmhRT1I5LSt4VgUOjJnJFPO2aHdI9vkNF858uTITs0@72Q/WW2G8mZ@wiBiOvKBDuzluJ/PnpgXhiW453n@bDCa23j3Gf25xlSev33sO4GbWO1kIkPbe02jSoxqOphTjKb@zENe3O5qsG2D@QP@5d@d6PGndIA5LzNI120xZ/dfkX) Example input is the output from `shortlog -n` from Retina.

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 9 bytes

```
NR<2,NF--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVjfb9s2EH7PX0FgHZKstdsU2DAUe8lSNw2QX7DTbQ8FBlqiZM4SqZFUHe9v29v@sOw7UpIp2U67NX0oWpk83X333Xd34qvlw8P19KfXL67fjUYPD1fcOKnYz//87ZwShh2dvH51/OaA@T8XSjrJC5bospSueXiapmzOrUxYZfQfImmff6hS7gSbTk7fXk3GZRodNyIX90xXTmplGVcpy42oWKlTYZtjV8Lkgs0NV8mCHZbcOmEOmc5YLt2ino/hwptyXgvv5Usj4DSP3mCrQjpvsPfaquCJGD6@QSyTsnJrlhU8Z07vvl1oXYUTmTb7bDn8bNdwtmTinpdVEf84r2WRkn2jtWOpNABLm3Vz4swIwuvy4mxyPRsAluqkLoVynBAjC0NUr/Qn0b7Rdq/IdJEK8/WITkUZ7DvcFrq27avAhEp2OduT8ck9oAKnXo826LxgvAME/688pq3/46fhAJxFggLLPGbbKXsn7@FEzlYwiJQmOlfSSpXvOksmpzViPjl51bo6jn4DQqbgVfTCK@7g@MDESPjyAelHhVTCM2oAYC/bkaduXenIUmWkcuTsI28MEFZ1USC8P2thHfsG7mdGl@zW6Nzw8t3Nby9NOXJl1c82soS0SOKTPz5OLBX4U7Ap40R8uP6C3UJv2MX@Xy6igMu6cNKCRKItP0Iprnp4q1yEB0fcsarsYejdxSXjc1079hYe4C2/8KIWp84ZOa@deCJJQlSFGBGijYedqsJQKVJJrvnwoIm2DWa@ZmlwajyEYhSwIGGyY/brxe3nlTdZcJWLQudPE5PMlTYCZoFxoza@kithrFboFLVt0fugZLZmkmLNfF1mUMAsE4aCDFG3hotCr1gp7z23s/6PDTkvSYypcdxFRQ4QnjNpmcJ1u9DGeV@Ojsfd3ZU2S2YFqs/JxJLxWUwZr5z@zBwRIxavCx7fXdB6B87en16fTy5vzgcnBkrRd9/qUgTQ0hq9Jgm6HijYeDSQDcSpLLqSMB1LfMrZUaqFVYeOoG4a61q44za/fCkGd318jeDh9BcHduapMzAGPiEBBFVScGs/V2helkmEbA0LPj1TcmLc6G3McBDLn7WRAjYaWxEzStK67oUzRAQKI39Kq9G80MmSDklV1duDSgbZC1wgD5RYdXovKVdD7fUg9mcWf/mu30rQOgjTlaHQQK1dkbUyDscacCLnnikmbMIr4Rv4RuHQM@HQ/c6SbY4d9nEf5s5HMLLeX@YWopUUn2jqxKPSy2WykOJTOKGrSlvZid8ew74PySIxehVEq55bJx1E03psqcVlQqT2cTPvtcuADN240ko/fvga@ZrzZGnBuEUk9rauKiOspcYvC8p@@/aNBLlAv7tRX3EQBbFgi81k9m4UZXnapDc87OAzvjQMsDOWF5HVQ324scFWC4mcSWWFcTagjL8MFMk9HnK/Ogmmnlde2XnlakOqUoMxHo4mFQRPj0HNLAwx30C376xnzrNvnnvGx88@@lpZs3Y3mJGkAX5n6gSOEPzkJwXZs15xY7uZ1LN@rHa9399ug4Ii5m4RN56SZBPpnIsF/yR1HfrOs@/24Ogz1Su4PQp1LtDoeCFt01cJndzougp7SlfeVRcMIv36Zkq64JsCplFLXdLotE7QWaETBCHo6LbXLrTZMEQ27nwbrysSZ0MRhqnQMz5eF/wJRJlDERHlTbyObVCw6PEyQ4tSrlhH3gblzKGTramumiriBdVTeANsd4VFsUVTKknGShTF0G@6c04rITlzimZ93u6H2xFSeUU9iXDYdXDPBtAW9MyvfGGgaqu6F9VUcDzBX8Tsv4TRzZQmwAEiUu9w0yvDi7dq73fvcwDAs7yTHUPjQU9ANvKmyVZDRT@Qz7otlaFJYJvs8rOH28Oi@JJfWmmcaeN3jR6L/j/f9@ic38eMXgoVdDrhNk5katbM1KoFZVDsw9m2meWbzk1AW5oJt5Qfqq18zjW9QsL5nvxvXyg39RTlB/HVBr4pkL9WEsvWYERpoQwXMQWIN/CxHQBF1N2opkd8xY14RJmnndbGoR80H3AmKvVfb37oPt4QtiU3y1SvFFXh7lWgvyp@/2OgGhBKhcNwULysKKbRSR96OLy0zdSi4y7h5310ZSK3Cw8wkAW0a@f/iTIyud93SRzAIdQZOET9hggXPpMAUz@yImTBy60yC22eHPioKN/cpAVNArCDinfIfdlcuaWl2duiWXtrUrDRvjUopqAdM0reHYFDoyZyRTxtmh3S3b9DRfOfLgyE7MvutkP1lthvJmfsIgojL8sQ7s5bkfzZ4YFwYluOd5/2hyNabx/zfW5z1ktau/cehc2oNrQWIumpptWmQjUeDy2EUX5jJ6xpB5uvGmB/R/6wd6V7P2ockAZE52kabaYt/9XlXw)

This one is just a test, consisting of two statements, without any associated code block.  The first test `NR<2` determines the truthy'ness of the test.  So the default code block, which is effectively `print $0`, is only run for the first line of the input.

The secondary statement, `NF--` just drop the last field in the input line.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
'(¡¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VjNbtw2EL77KQgkhe0mu4kDpChycxPHMRDHhu20PQQouBKlZS2RKkllvX2b3vsIPaUP5n5DSlpKu@ukjW9VDkGiJYcz38x88/P0OZ8diNvb3b1Pf3z68/b2lBsnFfvh77@cU8KwvYNnT/df7DD/50RJJ3nBEl2W0jUfD9OUzbiVCauM/lUk7ff3VcqdYBdHh69Oj6ZlGh03Ihc3TFdOamUZVynLjahYqVNhm2OnwuSCzQxXyZztltw6YXaZzlgu3byeTaHCi3JWC6/lEyOgNI9esFUhnRfYe7YqeCKGn89gy1FZuSXLCp4zpzffLrSuwolMm22yHH62SyhbMnHDy6qIf5zVskhJvtHasVQagKXNsjnx0gjC6@3Jy6N3lwPAUp3UpVCOE2IkYYjqqf4o2hdt90Smi1SYr0f0QpRBvsNtoWvbPoVIqGTnsy0eP7oBVIipZ5MVOo8Z7wDB/yuPaav/9H5iAMrCQSHKPGbrLnstb6BEzhYQCJcmOlfSSpVvOksiL2rYfHDwtFV1Gv0GhEzBq@jBU@6g@EDERPj0QdBPCqmEj6gBgD1vR5q6ZaUjSZWRypGyd7wYIKzqooB5v9XCOvYA6mdGl@zc6Nzw8vXZz09MOXFl1fc2vAS3SIonf3yaWErw@4imjFPgQ/XH7Bx8w062/3ISGVzWhZMWQSTa9COU4qyHtspFeHDYHbPKlgi9OnnL@EzXjr2CBnjlR17U4tA5I2e1E/dESbCqEBNCtNGwY1UIKkUqSTVvHjjRtsbMliwNSk2HUEwCFkRMdsp@Ojn/PPMmc65yUej8fmySudJGQCwwbtjGZ3IljNUKlaK2LXrvlcyWTJKtmc/LDAyYZcKQkcHqVnBR6AUr5Y2P7az/YxOcb4mMqXBcRUkOEB4xaZnCdTvXxnld9van3d2FNtfMCmSfk4kl4ZdxyHjm9GdmsBi2eF7w@G6C1ivw8s3hu@Ojt2fHgxMDpuirb3UpAmhpjVqTBF4PIdhoNKAN2KksqpIwXZR4l7O9VAurdh1B3RTWpXD7rX/5tRjc9fY1hIfTX2zYSx86A2GIJziAoEoKbu3nEs3TMpGQrSHBu@eClJg2fBtHOALLn7URAzYcW1FklMR13YOXsAghDP8prSazQifXdEiqql5vVDLQXogF0kCJRcf3knw15F4PYr9n8Zev@qUEpYMwXRgyDaG1ybKWxqFYA06k3EPFhE14JXwBXzEcaiYUutmYss2x3T7uQ995CybW68vcXLSU4h1NlXhSerpM5lJ8DCd0VWkrO/LbItjXIVkkRi8CadUz66QDaVqPLZW4TIjU3i3mjXYZkKEbp1rpuw@/g79mPLm2iLh5RPa2riojrKXCLwvyfvv6ioJcCL@rSZ9xYAVFwVo0k9irSeTli8a94WMHn/GpYYCdsbyIpO7q3ZUMtphL@EwqK4yzAWX8ZcBI7m6T@9lJMPW08szOK1cbYpUaEePhaFxB8PQiqOmFQeYr6Lad9ZHz8MEjH/Hxtw8@V5asnQ0uidIAvzN1AkUIftKTjOxJr7ixXU/qo36qNr3vb7dGgRFzN48LT0m0CXfOxJx/lLoOdefht1tw9J7qJdwWhjoWKHS8kLapq4RObnRdhTmlS@@qMwaWfn0xJV7wRQHdqKUqaXRaJ6is4AmCEOHo1sculNnQRDbqfBOPKxJnQxKGrtBHfDwu@BOwMgcjwsqzeBxboWBR42WGEqVcsYy0DcyZgydbUV02VRQXlE/hBcjuEotsi7pUooyFKIqh3nTnmEZCUuYQxfq4nQ/XLaT0imoS4bDp4JYJoE3oSz/yhYaqzeqeVReC4wv@osj@XRjddGkCMUCB1Dvc1Mrw8Fru/eJ1DgD4KO9ox1B70COQFb1pktWEom/IL7splaFIYJrs/LMltodJ8SW/tNR4qY2fNXpR9N/jfQvP@XnM6GuhAk8n3MaOTM2SmVq1oAySfdjbNr18U7kJaEs94Rrzg7WV97mmJySU79H/@oVylU@Rf2BfbaCbQvDXSmLYGrQoLZThIroA8QI6tg2giKob5fSEL7gRdzDzRce1sek7zQLnSKV@e/Ndt7whbEturlO9UJSFm0eB/qj4/PsQakAoFQ7NQfGkIpsmB33oofC1bboWHVcJ3@@jKlNwu/ABDVlAu3b@n0gjk/t5l8gBMYQ8QwxRvaGAC2sSYOpbVpgseLmWZqHMkwIfFPmbm7SgTgBykPEOvi@bK@c0NHtZ1GuvdQo2mrcGyRS445Kcd0XgUKsJX1GcNsUO7u7foaT5VxcGRPZld9umeo3sV50zZhGFlpdlMHfjrYj@7PBAOLFOx5tP@8NRWK8f83VuddZTWjv37oXJqDY0FsLpqabRpkI27g8lhFZ@JSeMaTurrQaivwv@MHelW5caO8QB0XnqRptuy29dxrXouBYd16LjWnRci45r0XEtOq5Fx7XouBYd16LjWnRci45r0XEtOq5Fx7XouBYd16LjWvR/thb9Bw)

Comment: Version without trailing space: `#¨ðý`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ṣ”(Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VjNbtw2EL77KQg0hZ0mu4kDtChycxPHMWDHge20PQQouBKlZSyRKkllvT31RXppX6IFeuuTpC/ifkNKWkq766RNblUOQaIlhzPfzHzz80YUxfLm5t0fv/398y97737/9ebm5pQbJxX75q8/nVPCsL39Rw/vPt5h/s@xkk7ygiW6LKVrPh6kKZtxKxNWGf1GJO33V1XKnWDnhwdPTw@nZRodNyIX10xXTmplGVcpy42oWKlTYZtjp8Lkgs0MV8mc7ZbcOmF2mc5YLt28nk2hwuNyVguv5QMjoDSPXrBVIZ0X2Hu2Kngihp/PYMthWbklywqeM6c33y60rsKJTJttshx@tksoWzJxzcuqiH@c1bJISb7R2rFUGoClzbI58cQIwuvk@Mnhi4sBYKlO6lIoxwkxkjBE9VS/Fe2Ltnsi00UqzMcjei7KIN/httC1bZ9CJFSy89kWjx9eAyrE1KPJCp37jHeA4P@Vx7TVf/ppYgDKwkEhyjxm6y57Jq@hRM4WEAiXJjpX0kqVbzpLIs9r2Ly//7BVdRr9BoRMwavowVPuoPhAxET49EHQTwqphI@oAYA9b0eaumWlI0mVkcqRsre8GCCs6qKAeT/Wwjr2GdTPjC7ZS6Nzw8tnZ98/MOXElVXf2/AS3CIpnvzxaWIpwT9FNGWcAh@q32cvwTfsePsvx5HBZV04aRFEok0/QinOemirXIQHh90xq2yJ0MvjE8ZnunbsKTTAK9/yohYHzhk5q534RJQEqwoxIUQbDTtWhaBSpJJU8@aBE21rzGzJ0qDUdAjFJGBBxGSn7Lvjl@9n3mTOVS4KnX8am2SutBEQC4wbtvGZXAljtUKlqG2L3islsyWTZGvm8zIDA2aZMGRksLoVXBR6wUp57WM76//YBOcJkTEVjssoyQHCPSYtU7hu59o4r8ve3Wl3d6HNFbMC2edkYkn4RRwynjn9mRkshi2eFzy@m6D1Cjx5fvDi6PDk7GhwYsAUffWtLkUALa1Ra5LA6yEEG40GtAE7lUVVEqaLEu9ytpdqYdWuI6ibwroU7m7rX34lBne9fQ3h4fQHG/bEh85AGOIJDiCokoJb@75E87RMJGRrSPDuOSclpg3fxhGOwPJnbcSADcdWFBklcV334AUsQgjDf0qryazQyRUdkqqq1xuVDLQXYoE0UGLR8b0kXw2514PY71n85ct@KUHpIEwXhkxDaG2yrKVxKNaAEyl3RzFhE14JX8BXDIeaCYWuN6Zsc2y3j/vQd96CifX6MjcXLaV4R1MlnpSeLpO5FG/DCV1V2sqO/LYI9nVIFonRi0Ba9cw66UCa1mNLJS4TIrW3i3muXQZk6MapVvr2wy/grxlPriwibh6Rva2ryghrqfDLgrzfvr6iIBfC73LSZxxYQVGwFs0k9nISefm8cW/42MFnfGoYYGcsLyKpu3p3JYMt5hI@k8oK42xAGX8ZMJK73eR@dhJMPa08s/PK1YZYpUbEeDgaVxA8vQhqemGQ@Qq6bWd95Nz57J6P@Pjba58rS9bOBhdEaYDfmTqBIgQ/6UlG9qRX3NiuJ/VRP1Wb3ve3W6PAiLmbx4WnJNqEO2dizt9KXYe6c@eLLTh6T/USbgtDHQkUOl5I29RVQic3uq7CnNKld9UZA0s/vpgSL/iigG7UUpU0Oq0TVFbwBEGIcHTrYxfKbGgiG3U@j8cVibMhCUNX6CM@Hhf8CViZgxFh5Vk8jq1QsKjxMkOJUq5YRtoG5szBk62oLpsqigvKp/ACZHeJRbZFXSpRxgJT6FBvunNEIyEpc4BifdTOh@sWUnpFNYlw2HRwywTQJvSFH/lCQ9Vmdc@qc8HxBX9RZP8kjG66NIEYoEDqHW5qZXh4Lfd@8DoHAHyUd7RjqD3oEciK3jTJakLRN@QX3ZTKUCQwTXb@2RLbw6T4kF9aarzQxs8avSj67/G@hef8PGb0lVCBpxNuY0emZslMrVpQBsk@7G2bXr6p3AS0pZ5wjfnB2sr7XNMTEsr36H/9QrnKp8g/sK820E0h@GslMWwNWpQWynARXYB4DB3bBlBE1Y1yesIX3IhbmPm849rY9J1mgXOoUr@9@apb3hC2JTdXqV4oysLNo0B/VPzy6xBqQCgVDs1B8aAimyb7feih8JVtuhYdVwnf76MqU3C78AENWUC7dv6fSCOT@3mXyAExhDxDDFG9oYALaxJg6ltWmCx4uZZmocyTAq8V@ZubtKBOAHKQ8Q6@L5srL2lo9rKo117rFGw0bw2SKXDHBTnvksChVhO@ojhtih3c3b9DSfOvLgyI7MPutk31GtmvOmfMIgotL8tg7sZbEf3Z4YFwYp2ON5/2h6OwXj/m69zqrKe0du7dC5NRbWgshNNTTaNNhWy8O5QQWvmVnDCm7ay2Goj@LvjD3JVuXWrsEAdE56kbbbotv3UZ16LjWnRci45r0XEtOq5Fx7XouBYd16LjWnRci45r0XEtOq5Fx7XouBYd16LjWnRci45r0f/ZWvQf)

My first Jelly answer!

**How?**

```
ṣ”(Ḣ - Main Link. Takes a string X on left
ṣ    - Split X on the occurrences of
 ”(  - Literal "("
   Ḣ - Head
```